# How can I have Exposed filter of Flag type in views?

Tags: flags, views

I want to add Exposed filters of flag types in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

I have many flag types and I want users to be able to select their favorite Flag type to show result.

Comment: So you want exposed filter of flag type i.e. Node, User, Taxonomy Terms, File, etc. right?

Comment: Hamed, the requirement of yours is not clear. Can you please add more description and the use case scenario?

Comment: @Nikhil Yes I want this.

Comment: @Nitesh I have many flag type . Users Can Flag content. I want to add exposed filters of flag types in views.

Comment: It is not possible then. In view you can only deal with one flag i.e. by adding relationship with flag and then use this flag as a exposed filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

- You can create taxonomy terms for your flag types.
- Add  term reference (taxonomy reference) field in your content type pointing to flag taxonomy.
- In your view, add filter of taxonomy terms then and check exposed filter checkbox.

You can use [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module for better UI.

Comment: Ankit, Hamed is using the Flag module which gives you the option to add various types of Flag. Though the requirement of his is not clear. But the approach that you have added is not what should be done. He won't have to add Term Reference field to meet his requirements.

Comment: Am I need install Flag Term? Flag Term Only can Use with Flag 2 version.

Comment: In your question your requirement was not clear how you create flag by using taxonomy terms or by using Flag module.
Right now above solution for taxonomy terms.

Comment: Just create a taxonomy term list for your flags and add one more field (field type : term reference) in your content type and point it to flag taxonomy after it in view just add a one more filter taxonomy terms with exposed filter.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement of yours is not doable.

Source - https://www.drupal.org/node/2218305#comment-8579757

You can only expose 1 flag at a time that too by adding a relationship of the flags on the views.